# Xcode 4 - Dynamic Interface Tutorial needed

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm trying to create a news viewer with Xcode 4. This should look like the following:

```
===============================
Title comes here -------    Date

Image

News Body
================================
```

As you can see, the news body must be pushed downward depending on the size of the image. The image must be pushed downward as the height of the title varies. I know I have to do some programming to position them dynamically. The only problem is I'm not familiar with `CGRect` and `Frame` things...

Where can I find a tutorial or sample code I can take a look and get some ideas?  Practical codes or tutorials would be appreciated as just reading documentation doesn't really give me a clear idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UILabel` provides `-sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` which will allow you to determine the size needed to fit the text you wish to display. I put together an example of resizing UILabels when I first ran into a similar problem and posted it here: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/07/10/resizing-uilabel-to-fit-text/

I'm afraid that's rather old now but I think should still be of some use.

Comment: Since there's a way to dynamically resize & position the label... I guess the rest is all about similarly calculating to position the following UIViews.... Thank you :)

Comment: Quite right @Raccoon. The approach I took was to layout the views assuming that the label only required a single line and then resize it, and it's parent view, sufficiently to fit the full text. For a sufficiently simple view layout that allows me to use the autoresizing mask of the UILabel's sibling views to reposition and scale them correctly when their common parent view is resized.